# Example of a non-nilpotent linear transformation that for every $v$ gives $A^n(v)=0$ for some $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, nilpotence

The question is as follows:
Give an example of a non-nilpotent linear transformation for some vector space with the following property, for every $v \in V$ there is an $n$ for which $A^n(v)=0$.

I really don't know how such a matrix would exist, since you can find a basis for this vector space, let's say $v_1,v_2,...$. Then we know for every $v_i$ there is an $n_i$ for which $A^{n_i}(v_i)=0$.

Then write $v$ as $\sum_{i}^{k} \alpha_i v_i$ and consider $A^{\sum_{i}^{k} n_i} (v)$, which gives $\sum_{i}^{k} \alpha_i \cdot A^{\sum_{i}^{k} n_i} (v_i)$ which should give zero for every $v_i$.

Maybe they meant an infinite vector space, however I doubt it since we never touched the infinite vector spaces in our algebra course.

Then you can consider the basis $B=v_1,v_2, ...$ an infinite basis over some field and let $A(v_1)=0$ and $A(v_i)=v_{i-1}$ then since there exist online finite amount of non-zero coordinates then there must be an $n$ for which $A^n(v)=0$, however the transformation is not nilpotent.

So my question is whether it's really true that such a transformation doesn't exist for finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: If $V$ has a finite basis $(e_{1},...e_{n})$, and $A$ has such property, there exists some $N$ which satisfies $A^{N}(e_{i})=0$ for all $i$, hence $A^{N}$ is the zero map. That's why there aren't counterexamples in finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: For infinite dimensional spaces your idea is correct as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be the space of all polynomial functions from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ and let $A\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=p'(x)$. If $\deg p(x)=n$, then $A^{n+1}\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=0$, but $A$ is not nilpotent: for any $n\in\Bbb N$,$$A\left(x^{n+1}\right)=(n+1)!\ne0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The vector space is neceessarily infinite dimensional. Consider the space of all real sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Define $A(x_n)=(x_2,x_3,..)$. If $x_n=0$ for $n>N$ then $A^{N}(x_n)=0$. But, for any $N$,  $Ae_{N+1} \neq 0$ so $A$ is not nilpotent. [$e_i$ is the sequence which has $1$ in the $i-$th coordinate and $0$ elsewhere].

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question at the end (which is not the question of the title): indeed such a transformation does not exist for any finite dimensional vector space. Applying the given property for $v$ running over a basis of the vector space, we get a finite list of exponents $n$ such that each basis vector is in $\ker(A^n)$ for some $n$ in the list. But then for the maximum $m$ of those exponents (taking $m=0$ if the list is empty because I am pedantic about not discriminating against $0$-dimensional spaces), $\ker(A^m)$ contains each vector of the basis, and being a subspace it must be the entire space.